# How can I interact with my deployed contract without Remix interface?

Tags: solidity

Very basic question.

I've deployed a smart contract on Goerli network https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x9598510ea769c85c5e836c78470c8ad1a1627bfa

It's a simple faucet and I'd like to try and withdraw funds from it, but do it without Remix interface, i.e. do it in VSCode -- how can I do it?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.16;

contract Faucet {

    function withdraw(uint withdraw_amount) public {

        require(withdraw_amount <= 1000000000000000000);

        payable(msg.sender).transfer(withdraw_amount);
    }

    fallback() external payable {}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Geth and make a private network over their you can see the official documentation of Geth and connect to any network you want

Answer (score 1):

There are a few way you can do this.

1. Using Truffle/Hardhat, connect to Goerli network and use web3/ethers to create instance of contract (just needs contract ABI, and address) and a wallet to sign transaction. Then you can call the different functions in that contract.
2. You can use infrastructure providers such as Alchemy/Infura which provides API to send a raw transaction to the contract on Goerli network. You will still need to create and sign the transaction yourself before sending to API provider.
3. Create web application with web3/ethers to set-up contract instance with the contract ABI and address, then use your browser wallet to handle the transaction composing and signing to Goerli network.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is, you can also verify and publish your contract in etherscan first, and in the contract tab, you will see 'Code', 'Read Contract' and 'Write Contract'.

You can interact with your contract by connecting your wallet to the site in 'Write Contract' part.

From my test though, the 'Read Contract' part will not use your account from your wallet so msg.sender will not be your account's address.

[image]